# javascript interest calculator over multiple years

Tags: javascript

I need to make three textboxes with date of birth, amount (money) and interest.

with click on the button a overview of doubled amount should appear if I put my money on the bank at a certain interest rate.

I don't know how to start.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I assume you are looking for a plain javascript/HTML solution. Your text boxes should be simple `<input>`. Start with that. See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: @mankowitz please don't post w3school links. Its content can be really inacurate and is definitely not affiliated to W3C

Comment: @cid - I find w3schools is good for getting started, which is where Sadaf is right now. It also lets you try out code on the site, which is convenient. But I understand your concern. Where would you have him start?

Comment: [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn)

Answer (score 0):

**Textboxes:**

Generally, for creating User Interface on the web, you will write [**HTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML). Using your case, for example, we know you need three textboxes. I would use [`<input>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) like this:

**Step 1**

```
<input name="dob" type="date" />
<input name="amount" type="number" step="0.01" />
<input name="interest" type="number" step="0.001" />
```

**Step 2**

We can further wrap these to add text labels using [`<label>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label), like so:

```
<label>
  Date of Birth
  <input name="dob" type="date" />
</label>
<label>
  Amount
  <input name="amount" type="number" step="0.01" />
</label>
<label>
  Interest
  <input name="interest" type="number" step="0.001" />
</label>
```

**Step 3**

Then, to link them together, we wrap them using a [`<form>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form):

```
<form>
  <label>
    Date of Birth
    <input name="dob" type="date" />
  </label>
  <label>
    Amount
    <input name="amount" type="number" step="0.01" />
  </label>
  <label>
    Interest
    <input name="interest" type="number" step="0.001" />
  </label>
</form>
```

**Step 4**

Finally, we need elements for calculation. I would use the aptly-named [`<output>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output) and a [`<button>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) to submit the form:

```
<form>
  <label>
    Date of Birth
    <input name="dob" type="date" />
  </label>
  <label>
    Amount
    <input name="amount" type="number" step="0.01" />
  </label>
  <label>
    Interest
    <input name="interest" type="number" step="0.001" />
  </label>
  <label>
    Total
    <output name="total">0</output>
  </label>

  <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

**Calculation:**

As you see above, [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) is an interactive element that generally has a `name` and `value`. `value` can be updated by someone using your page or via [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript), after the elements in question have been [fully loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event). To update these elements and get values for your calculations via JavaScript, you would use something called the [DOM (Document Object Model)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and react to user input by "listening" to [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) (like "click", for example). The form fires an event called "submit" when you click the "Calculate" button in the example above. We can use that instead of "click", which makes it easier to handle everything inside the form (like the textboxes). For example:

```
// Step 1: Create a JavaScript function (actually gets run later)
const calcForm = form => {

  // Get values (and totalElement) from form.elements
  const {
    amount: {value: amount},
    interest: {value: interest},
    total: totalElement,
  } = form.elements

  // Update the totalElement with interest * amount
  totalElement.value = (interest * amount).toFixed(2)
}

// Step 2: Wait for the DOM to fully load (so formElement exists)
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

  // Step 3: Get form element using the "js-form" class
  const formElement = document.querySelector('.js-form')

  // Step 4: Run calcForm on "submit" event
  formElement.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    calcForm(e.target)
  })

  // Step 5: Run calcForm at start
  calcForm(formElement)
})
```

One helpful thing to do is use classes as JavaScript "hooks", so I also changed the form HTML to read: `<form class="js-form">` at this step. I use js- prefixes on classes to make it clear where it is used (that is, not [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS)). You'll notice the line that says [`document.querySelector('.js-form')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)...this is what gets the `<form>` as an object in JavaScript.

Finally, putting all of this together, here's a working snippet with some basic (fully optional) [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS) styling, but:

```js
const calcForm = form => {
  const {
    amount: {value: amount},
    interest: {value: interest},
    total: totalElement,
  } = form.elements
  totalElement.value = (amount * interest).toFixed(2)
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const formEl = document.querySelector('.js-form')
  formEl.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    calcForm(e.target)
  })
  calcForm(formEl)
})
```

```css
.form {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: min-content;
  justify-items: end;
  text-align: right;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.form__label {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.form__input {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: inherit;
}
```

```html
<form class="js-form form">
  <label class="form__label">
    Date of Birth
    <input class="form__input" name="dob" type="date" />
  </label>
  <label class="form__label">
    Amount
    <input class="form__input" name="amount" type="number" step="0.01" value="50.00" />
  </label>
  <label class="form__label">
    Interest
    <input class="form__input" name="interest" type="number" step="0.001" value="0.025" />
  </label>
  <label class="form__label">
    Total
    <output name="total">0</output>
  </label>

  <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
```